# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Laravel Blade. In dd correct values

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I am tying to use some data in my blade.php. Among other things I want to show the street name and the status.

This is the relevant code in my blade.php:

```
@foreach($form['streets'] as $street)
   <tr>
       <td>{{$street['name']}}</td>
       <td>{{$street['status']}}</td>
       <td>
       <a href="#">Zie pdf</a>
       </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

dd $form:

```
array:4 [▼
  "id" => 2456
  "name" => "Some name"
  "percentage" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "done" => 4
      "ndone" => 0
      "started" => 0
      "nvt" => 56
    ]
  ]
  "streets" => array:4 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "Name"
      "status" => "Klaar"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "Name"
      "status" => "Klaar"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "Name"
      "status" => "Klaar"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "Name"
      "status" => "Klaar"
    ]
  ]
]
```

dd $forms:

```
array:5 [▼
  "projectName" => "Some Name"
  "projectCode" => "abc123456"
  "totalHouses" => 60
  "totalForms" => null
  "forms" => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "id" => 2456
      "name" => "Some Name"
      "percentage" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:4 [▼
          "done" => 4
          "ndone" => 0
          "started" => 0
          "nvt" => 56
        ]
      ]
      "streets" => array:4 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          "name" => "Some Street 1"
          "status" => "Klaar"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
          "name" => "Some Street 2"
          "status" => "Klaar"
        ]
        2 => array:2 [▼
          "name" => "Some Street 3"
          "status" => "Klaar"
        ]
        3 => array:2 [▼
          "name" => "Some Street 4"
          "status" => "Klaar"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
     "id" => 2489
     "name" => "Some Name"
     "percentage" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:4 [▼
          "done" => 6
          "ndone" => 0
          "started" => 0
          "nvt" => 54
        ]
      ]
      "streets" => array:2 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          "name" => "Some Street 5"
          "status" => "Klaar"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
          "name" => "Some Street 6"
          "status" => "Klaar"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "totalForms" => 6
  ]
]
```

So when I try to dd (dump and die) the $street it does get the correct values, and when I put `['name']` behind it, it also works. But when I run the code without any dd it fails.

So I want to use the name and status per house. But for some reason I get an error on the foreach for $street.

I would like to know why and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a loop over `@foreach($form['streets'] as $street)`, for example `@foreach($forms as $form)`? If so, you probably have one or more forms which are incorrect even though the first one is. When you add a `dd()` the code stops executing before reaching the incorrect `$form`.

I suggest you `dd()` all the `$forms` and check the `streets` of all of them.

Comment: You are correct. I do have a $forms (not that exact name) where i get $form out of. I just did what you said and it seems if my code should work.

Comment: Can you post the output?

Comment: That's the same as `dd($form)` which can't be right ;)

Comment: Yeah I realized, just edited again with the correct values :)

Comment: I can't see anything wrong either. Check the exact line the error points to (in `storage/framework/views/*.php`), perhaps it's actually somewhere different.

Comment: Yeah I don't know. It says on the line for the foreach in $form['streets'] as $street. Either way. Thank you very much for trying

Comment: Only other thing that comes to mind is you might have another outer loop with different forms.

Comment: You were right, it was something else. I didn't call correctly on $form['totalForms'] somewhere earlier in the code. Your comment made me think about other times that the code would give error on something completely different than it actually had a problem with

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
<td>{{ $street->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $street->status }}</td>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. however this is not the solution just jet. I get now the error Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Answer (score 0):

**try to use like below**

```
@foreach($form->streets as $street)
   <tr>
    <td>
      @if(isset($street['name']))
        {{ $street['name'] }}
      @endif
    </td>
    <td>
      @if(isset($street['status']))
        {{ $street['status'] }}
      @endif
    </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: check now @SilkeNL

Comment: Thank you for you edit. Now I just get error Trying to get property 'streets' of non-object. It should all be array's not objects?

Comment: for debugging print it {{ $form }} and check the object, it all key exist or not?

Comment: Yes the key exists